# Bootstrap - how use cols?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do responsive navbar on my site. I would like to have one small img on the left of navbar, and then I would like to have two lines of text - one under another, just next by my img. And there is a problem with my cols. When screen is between 750 and 950 pc then something wrong is with my texts, and I think, that they haven't these cols which I made then, 
how to correct this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid col-md-12">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class=" col-sm-2" style="float: left">
            <img alt="Brand" src="buty2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="navbar-text">Some text</div>
            <div class="navbar-text">Some text under first text</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first thing is, you need to use the "row" class and within that nest a div with the class col-sm-2 and another div with col-sm-10. IF you want to have an image to the left, nest that image in a span with a class of pull-right and another span or div next to that with span/div with class pull-left.

row
-col2
--div.pull-right
--div.pull-left
-col10

Is that what you were looking for? Also, you can use columns for different media queries, such as doing smaller columns for smaller resolutions and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `col-md-12` at the  first `div` with `row` to start the row.

But i think `navbar-right` and `navbar-left` or `navbar brand` are that what you are looking for.

See this:
[Bootstrap Navbar Components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

If you really want to use the Grid System read this clearly.
[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

In this case my favorit will be the navbar method. Try it ;)